# Drop Down List Value vs. Text

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a tiny problem, with a DropDownList. This DDL is populated with items in Page Load like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

    If Page.IsPostBack = False Then

                ' Fill Activity DDL
                Dim ActivitiesAdapter As New ActivitiesTableAdapters.ActivitiesTableAdapter
                Dim GetActivities As Activities.ActivitiesDataTable = ActivitiesAdapter.GetDataByOnPlantAndOrderType(OrderType, Plant)

                If GetActivities.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    DDL_Activity_Name.Items.Clear()

                    Dim ActivityList As New List(Of ListItem)
                    ActivityList.Add(New ListItem("Please select ..."))

                    For b = 0 To GetActivities.Rows.Count - 1
                        Dim ActivityRow As Activities.ActivitiesRow = GetActivities(b)
                        Dim ActivityName As String = Nothing
                        Dim ActivityID As Integer = Nothing
                        If ActivityRow.IsNull("ActivityName") = False Then
                            ActivityName = ActivityRow.ActivityName
                        End If
                        If ActivityRow.IsNull("ActivityID") = False Then
                            ActivityID = ActivityRow.ActivityID
                        End If
                        ' First goes the Name then the ID
                        ActivityList.Add(New ListItem(ActivityName, ActivityID))
                    Next

                    DDL_Activity_Name.DataSource = ActivityList
                    DDL_Activity_Name.DataBind()

                End If

    End If
End Sub
```

After the page has loaded, a user must select an activity from this DDL. Based on selected Activity I fill another DropDownList. Here is the catch: I need the ActivityID (the value property of the selected item). So I created a SelectedIndex event  :

```
 Protected Sub DDL_Activity_Name_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DDL_Activity_Name.SelectedIndexChanged

    ' At load page I added for every item a text property (ActivityName), and a value property (ActivityID)
    Dim SelectedActivityID As String = Nothing
    SelectedActivityID = DDL_Activity_Name.SelectedItem.Value

    Dim SelectedActivityName As String = Nothing
    SelectedActivityName = DDL_Activity_Name.SelectedItem.Text

End sub
```

My problem is that both SelectedItem.Value and SelecteItem.Text returns the same value.
I checked the code in page load, and all my listitems from DDL_Activity_Name are filled with proper info. Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On DDL_Activity_Name set DataTextField = "Text" and DataValueField = "Value"

DDL_Activity_Name has to know what are the fields where the text and value are stored.